# Understanding the correct use of magrittr pipe `%>%` syntax

Tags: r, pipe, operator-precedence, magrittr

I have a named numeric vector, where I am trying to divide each element by the sum of all elements. Then I want to use the `signif` function to round to the significant figure. This is easy enough doing it "old school", by computing the division and storing the variable, then subsequently using the stored variable to compute the significant figures. However, if I try to pipe the computation directly using the `magrittr`pipe operator (`%>%`), `signif` doesn't really do anything with the vector.

I am trying to understand what the distinction is, as I frequently run into issues with piping in combination with base R functions.

Here's an example, with the output I am getting:

```
> # My named vector
> v <-setNames(c(1:5), letters[1:5])

> # Dividing each element by the total sum and rounding to significant figures
> a <- v/sum(v)
> a <- signif(a, digits = 3)

> # Dividing each element by the total sum and piping directly to signif()
> b <- v/sum(v) %>% signif(digits = 3)

> a
> b

a: 0.0667   b 0.133   c 0.2   d 0.267   e 0.333

a: 0.0666666666666667 b: 0.133333333333333 c: 0.2 d: 0.266666666666667 e: 0.333333333333333
```

Comment: There is a typo in your code `a <- signif(v, ` it should be `a <- signif(a, .`  Otherwise, the %>% can be `(v/sum(v)) %>% signif(digits = 3)`

Comment: Look for the `?Syntax` operator precedence and check `v %>% signif(digits = 3) %>% {./sum(.)}`

Comment: From what I can see `* /` comes after `%any%`. Does this mean that try to pipe before it completes the division?

Comment: That's right ...

Comment: @akrun Yor code sample actually helped with a different problem I've been facing: how to pipe into a comptutation like this. Using regular/round brackets doesn't really work here. What exactly does the curly brackets do?

Comment: @akrun I can't find any documentation on this. Would you care to elaborate or recommend any pages etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following @akrun's hint: `?Syntax` has

```
  ‘%any% |>’         special operators (including ‘%%’ and ‘%/%’) 
       ‘* /’              multiply, divide
```

showing that the pipe operator has higher precedence than `/`, so that your expression is effectively

```r
v/(sum(v) %>% signif(digits = 3))
```

Adding parentheses will help: try

```r
(v/sum(v)) %>% signif(digits = 3)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! This is likely to avoid a lot of hair pulling and destruction of property in the immediate vicinity in the future, I'm sure.